# how could i count longest sequence of 01 in list

Tags: python

i need to count longest 01 from list
ex:

```
[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

suppose to print 4 (sequence could also start with 10):

```
1,0,1,0  =   2
```

```
import itertools


with open("file.txt", 'r+') as file:
    file_context = file.read()
    print(file_context)

def func1(arg):
  global key
  key = list(arg)
  print(key)
func1(file_context)


A = [0,1,0,1]
key2 = [ int(x) for x in key ]

c=0
k = max(len(list(lent)) for (A[c],lent) in itertools.groupby(A) if A[c]==0 and A[c+1]==1)
print(k)
```

Comment: since you are reading from a file a regex could also be a possibility

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a fairly straightforward double loop - i.e., two iterations checking for 0,1 then 1,0 pairs

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

ms = 0

for t in [0, 1], [1, 0]:
    i, c = 0, 0
    while i < len(lst)-1:
        if lst[i:i+2] == t:
            c += 1
            i += 1
        elif c > 0:
            ms = max(ms, c)
            c = 0
        i += 1

print(max(ms, c))
```

**Output:**

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a regular expression you can work directly on `string`-data, no further casting to `int`, `list`, ... is needed. Here an example:

```
import re

with open("file.txt", 'r+') as file:
    file_context = file.read()

# remove extra whitespaces and commas
file_context = file_context.replace(', ', '').strip('][') # edited

# search by pattern
matches_01 = re.findall(r'((?:01)+)', file_context)
matches_10 = re.findall(r'((?:10)+)', file_context)

# get lengths
max_01 = len(max(matches_01, key=len, default=[])) // 2 # edited: added default
max_10 = len(max(matches_10, key=len, default=[])) // 2

max_length = max(max_01, max_10)

# result
print(f'Length longest sequence: {max_length}')
```

---

A quick fix to find the position of the occurrence of the longest sequence (only the 1st match in case of multiple possibilities) is to use `str.find`

```
... [ + check the edits from above]
if max_length > 0:
    position = file_context.find('01'*max_length)
    if position == -1:
        position = file_context.find('10'*max_length)
    print('Position', position)
```

A more elegant way would be to use `finditer` instead of `findall`.

Comment: Ok  and how do i find start index of longest seq?

Comment: @Marko Halushka edited. Careful to the edit of the original answer. Notice further that the amount of statements ca n be reduced by chaining the result of `findall` as a single list